# error: package android.support.annotation does not exist

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

i am having an issue with the android.support.annotation package..
this is my main build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"

    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        // instead of 'implementation' here, you should insert 'implementation' in android/app/build.gradle'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
           // Local Maven repo containing AARs with JSC library built for Android
          url "$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist"
       }
    }
}



subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 28 
                buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my \android\build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal 
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.1, 0.99.99]'
    }
}


apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.course"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 35
        versionName "1.1.32"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
       pickFirst '**/libjsc.so'
       pickFirst '**/libc++_shared.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
   }

}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_cameraroll')
    implementation project(':react-native-reanimated')
    implementation project(':react-native-i18n')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_async-storage')       
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-randombytes')
    implementation project(':react-native-sentry')
    implementation project(':react-native-appsee')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-resizer')
    implementation project(':react-native-onesignal')
    implementation project(':react-native-mixpanel')
    implementation project(':react-native-svg')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-fs')
    implementation project(':react-native-wheel-pick')
    implementation project(':react-native-fast-image')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    // implementation project(':realm')
    implementation project(':react-native-camera')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
    implementation(project(':react-native-onesignal')){
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }

    // implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
    //   exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    // }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'

    implementation 'org.webkit:android-jsc-cppruntime:+'
    // For even older gradle
    // compile 'org.webkit:android-jsc-cppruntime:+'
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'

}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}


configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
        force 'org.webkit:android-jsc:r241213'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

I already added this piece of code to my gradle.properties:

```
...
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

this is the full error message that I get:

> Gradle may disable incremental compilation as the following annotation
>   processors are not incremental: jetified-compiler-4.7.1.jar
>   (com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1). Consider setting the
>   experimental feature flag
>   android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true in the
>   gradle.properties file to run annotation processing in a separate task
>   and make compilation incremental. Note: [2] Wrote
>   GeneratedAppGlideModule with:
>   [com.bumptech.glide.integration.okhttp3.OkHttpLibraryGlideModule,
>   com.dylanvann.fastimage.FastImageOkHttpProgressGlideModule]
>   C:\Users\Ofir\Desktop\Vegan
>   Nation\VeganNation\node_modules\react-native-fast-image\android\build\generated\source\apt\debug\com\dylanvann\fastimage\GlideOptions.java:6:
>   error: package android.support.annotation does not exist import
>   android.support.annotation.CheckResult;
>                                    ^ C:\Users\Ofir\Desktop\Vegan Nation\VeganNation\node_modules\react-native-fast-image\android\build\generated\source\apt\debug\com\dylanvann\fastimage\GlideOptions.java:7:
>   error: package android.support.annotation does not exist import
>   android.support.annotation.NonNull;
>                                    ^ C:\Users\Ofir\Desktop\Vegan Nation\VeganNation\node_modules\react-native-fast-image\android\build\generated\source\apt\debug\com\dylanvann\fastimage\GlideRequest.java:8:
>   error: package android.support.annotation does not exist import
>   android.support.annotation.CheckResult;
>                                    ^ C:\Users\Ofir\Desktop\Vegan Nation\VeganNation\node_modules\react-native-fast-image\android\build\generated\source\apt\debug\com\dylanvann\fastimage\GlideRequest.java:9:
>   error: package android.support.annotation does not exist import
>   android.support.annotation.NonNull;
>                                    ^ C:\Users\Ofir\Desktop\Vegan Nation\VeganNation\node_modules\react-native-fast-image\android\build\generated\source\apt\debug\com\dylanvann\fastimage\GlideRequests.java:7:
>   error: package android.support.annotation does not exist import
>   android.support.annotation.CheckResult;
>                                    ^ C:\Users\Ofir\Desktop\Vegan Nation\VeganNation\node_modules\react-native-fast-image\android\build\generated\source\apt\debug\com\dylanvann\fastimage\GlideRequests.java:8:
>   error: package android.support.annotation does not exist import
>   android.support.annotation.NonNull;

Thank you!

Comment: Just navigate to the paths where are being shown in error. You will find that the import used is `android.support.annotation.NonNull`. Replace them with `androidx.annotation.NonNull`

Comment: I tried to do the replacement in the first file.
After running npx react-native run-android it replaces the androidx back to android.annotations.... any help? -.-"

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `react-native` < 0.60, you have to install [jetifier](https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier#readme) tool

```
npm install --save-dev jetifier
npx jetify
npx react-native run-android
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "postinstall": "npx jetify"
}
```

Comment: i use react-native v0.59.9. it did not fix the issue... thanks